# how to update stored data from url?

Tags: yql

After creating a record in yql's hosted storage using the following:

```
insert into yql.storage.admin (url) values ("http://hostingdomain.com/mytable.xml")
```

how can I update that record from a url ?

The documentation only shows:

```
update yql.storage set value="new value" where name="store://3cc85a99-6a89-4600-ade1-f7f83ecc4b83"
```

but this requires you to input the value directly instead of fetching it from a url.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be interested, I found the answer:

```
update yql.storage set url="[url]" where name="store://[updatename]"
```